# How do I handle "No error handler for XPC error: Connection invalid"?

Tags: ios, callkit

Scenario: 
I'm building a rudimentary CallKit demo with the following exitAction within a UIViewController:

```
 @IBAction func exitAction(_: UIBarButtonItem) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
    }
}
```

When this action fires, I get the following log shown within the Xcode console:

> ...[client] No error handler for XPC error: Connection invalid

This always happens, independently from the CallKit state. 
Remedy?